# iOS - Setting alpha to view causing in showing strange border to appear

Tags: ios, objective-c

Basically I am doing a recursive search to set the alpha of all child views to 0.5.

Later I want to set the alpha back to their original values, so I set the alpha  to 1.0f. But it results in this:

[image]

If I click in the UITextField, lines disappear. How can I restore all my subviews to their default alpha without this strange border appearing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like an [**XY problem**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You should not be messing with the view hierarchy of system controls like `UITextField`s.

If you set the alpha of a superview it affects the alpha of that view and all of it's subviews, so there shouldn't be any reason to do this.